# ¿Hay una forma de obtener el IntRange correspondiente a un arreglo?

Tags: kotlin

puedo crear un rango manualmente

```
var a = 1..10
```

Para después iterar sobre ese rango

```
for(i in a){
  print(i)
}
```

Pero quería saber si los arreglos tienen una propiedad que me permita sacar el rango que abarcan sus indices.

De manera que la iteración sobre el array me quede así:

```
  for(k in array.teoricamenteUnRango){
    array[k]
  }
```

De forma que tenga el indice en la variable guardado en `k` en lugar del valor almacenado en la posición del array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay una propiedad que se llama `indices`, me devuelve el rango que abarca los indices del array.

```
 for(k in array.indices){
    print(array[k])
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Si no quieres usar el mapa/lista original para hacer un lookup de lo que ya estás iterando:

Para una lista puedes usar `withIndex` que devuelve un iterable de `IndexedValue`

```
var list = listOf(4,5,6,7,8,9)

for ((k, v) in list.withIndex()) {
    println(k)
    println(v)

}
```

Para un mapa no hace falta hacer nada especial

```
var map = mapOf("key" to 4, "key2" to 5, "key3" to 6)

for ((k, v) in map) {
    println(k)
    println(v)
}
```

Si no te interesa el valor para nada puedes usar `indices` para la lista que devolverá el `IntRange`

```
for (k in list.indices) {
    println(k)
}
```

Para un mapa no hay `indices` ya que el index es la key del EntryMap.
Pero puedes ignorar el valor o usar `map.keys` para obtener un Set con solo las keys y a eso le puedes llamar `indices` para obtener la posición numérica.